# dependency injection with multiple class constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the class as:

```
public class ServiceUtility
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
    public ServiceUtility(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }
    public string GetFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        return _environment.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(fileName)?.PhysicalPath;
    }
}
```

**Using in Startup.cs**

```
services.AddScoped<ServiceUtility>();
```

Using *ServiceUtility* in another class:

```
public class LevelUp
{
        private readonly ServiceUtility _serviceUtility;
        public LevelUp(ServiceUtility serviceUtility)
        {
            _serviceUtility = serviceUtility;
        }
        public LevelUp(string input)
        {
          //here the _serviceUtility is null
        }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

From controller I am using as:

```
var object = userList.Select(x => new LevelUp(x.Description));
```

When I am using the `_serviceUtility` in `Levelup(string input)` constructor, the value is always null.

I have also added in Startup.cs class:

```
services.AddScoped<LevelUp>();
```

What I am doing wrong here, what is the proper way of dependency injection with multiple constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you are (manually) calling the `LevelUp` constructor with the `string` parameter (`ctor(string)`) and not the `ctor(ServiceUtility)` constructor. This `LevelUp` class is not created by the DI Container, you are creating it yourself. If you wish to supply `ServiceUtility` to `LevelUp`, you should pass both the `string` and `ServiceUtility` through the same constructor:

```cs
public class LevelUp
{
    private readonly ServiceUtility _serviceUtility;

    public LevelUp(ServiceUtility serviceUtility, string input)
    {
        _serviceUtility = serviceUtility;
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

From within your controller you then have to pass `ServiceUtility` as well to `LevelUp`'s constructor:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ServiceUtility serviceUtility;

    public HomeController(ServiceUtility serviceUtility)
    {
        this.serviceUtility = serviceUtility;
    }

    public object Index(List userList)
    {
        var object =
            userList.Select(x => new LevelUp(this.serviceUtility, x.Description));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, there isn't way of doing that by the `framework` itself? Why do we need to supply by ourselves?

Comment: It's one way or the other: either you leave the construction or the object completely to the DI infrastructure (which means a DI Container or a [hand-written](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ)) -or- you create the object using the `new` statement. A DI Container can't magically change your compiled code.

Comment: Also note that when when it comes to classes that contain application behavior and are injected with dependencies, it is considered to be [a bad thing](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/) for them to have multiple constructors.

Comment: Thank you @steven i will certainly note that. and I will try to refactor the multiple constructors.

Comment: On the other hand, your `LevelUp` seems more a [newable](https://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) than an injectable. For data-centric objects it's okay to have multiple constructors.